# check if storage is available and if it is execute a backup routine with passwordphrase

Tags: applescript, command-line, automator, password, keychain

i installed restic backup program with homebrew and tested its performance. Its great. So i wold like to set up a automated routine.
I tried to do it in automator with a workflow but because of the password check it aborts. 
Maybe you wold solve different please let me know...

What im trying to get:

```
1. check if storage is available (usb storage attached)
2. execute restic -r /Volumes/usb-storage-name/restic-backups backup /Users/user/data
3. prompt the encryption key (or get it from keychain account restic?)
4. check again a day later...
```

what i have tried:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps 1, 2 and 4 are relatively straightforward and can be performed using `launchd` (or `cron`) to call a script.

My solution involves some setup, taken from [this blog post](http://blog.macromates.com/2006/keychain-access-from-shell/):

Open `Keychain Access` (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> `Keychain Access`), click on `Password`, then <kbd>+</kbd> to create a new password. User `restic` for the `Keychain Item Name` and for the `Account Name`. Enter the password you intend to use in the `Password` field (i.e. enter the same password you used when you ran `restic init`). Finally, click `Add` to complete the set-up process.

1. `launchd` (or `cron`) job runs every 24 hours and simply calls a shell script `restic-backup.sh`
2. `restic-backup.sh` checks if `/Volumes/usb-storage-name` is mounted, and halts if it isn't. If the drive is mounted it then checks for the existence of the `/Users/user/data` directory, and halts if the directory doesn't exist (it can't backup a non-existent directory!) If the backup volume is mounted and the source directory exists it then moves on to step 3...
3. [If the environment variable `RESTIC_PASSWORD` is set Restic will use its value instead of prompting for a password](http://restic.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.0/Manual/#initialize-a-repository). `restic-backup.sh` will set `RESTIC_PASSWORD` using the `security` command and some `ruby` magic:

   ```
   RESTIC_PASSWORD=$(security 2>&1 >/dev/null find-generic-password -ga restic |ruby -e 'print $1 if STDIN.gets =~ /^password: "(.*)"$/')
   ```

   With `RESTIC_PASSWORD` set the script can now execute the backup:

   ```
   restic -r /Volumes/usb-storage-name/restic-backups backup /Users/user/data
   ```
4. The `launchd`/`cron` job from step 1 should run every 24 hours, covering step 4 as well.

`restic-backup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# USER CONFIGURATION:    
resticuser=restic
srcdir=/Users/user/data
backupvolume=/Volumes/usb-storage-name
backupdir=${backupvolume}/restic-backups

# Script vars:
longname=$0
shortname=$(/usr/bin/basename "${longname}")

printf '%s %s (%s) running...\n' "$(date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" "${shortname}" "${longname}"

if [[ ! -d "${srcdir}" ]]; then
    printf '%s %s does NOT exist.' "$(date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" "${srcdir}" >&2
    exit 1
else
    if [[ $(mount | grep "${backupvolume}") ]]; then
        # See: http://blog.macromates.com/2006/keychain-access-from-shell/
        # Parse output of 'security' and set RESTIC_PASSWORD:
        export RESTIC_PASSWORD=$(security 2>&1 >/dev/null find-generic-password -ga ${resticuser} |ruby -e 'print $1 if STDIN.gets =~ /^password: "(.*)"$/')
        # Run backup, capturing output in case of error:
        output=$(restic -r ${backupdir} backup "${srcdir}")
        error=$?
        if [[ "${error}" == "0" ]]; then
            printf '%s Restic backup completed successfully.\n' "$(date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"
        else
            printf '%s Restic backup failed: error code: %s, error: %s\n' \
                    "$(date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" "${error}" "${output}" >&2
        fi
    else
        printf '%s %s is NOT mounted.' "$(date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" "${backupvolume}" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
fi

printf '%s %s ended.\n' "$(date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" "${shortname}"
```

Comment: I've tested this using a USB hard-drive (and with much more extensive logging) - errors may have crept in to the script when I changed my own user config and ripped out the chatty logging. Let me know if you run into problems. I haven't tested this with `launchd` but could fairly quickly throw together a `launchd plist` if you need one.

Comment: Perfect! That runs smoth. I made a follow up Question here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273557/check-if-storage-is-available-and-if-it-is-execute-a-backup-routine-with-passwor
Maybe you can help me on this addon...?